# Launch node & chrome after system boot

Tags: raspberry-pi, init, node.js

I've a RaspberryPi, and I would like to run a nodeJS script (running a server), and then open Chrome when the server has been launched.

Currently, I launch my nodeJS script thanks to a script in `/etc/init.d` and chromium thanks to a line in  `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`

The problem is chromium is launched BEFORE my server is up, thus, it displays an error and I have to manually refresh the page in order to make it work.

Do you have any tips on how to handle this situation?

```
pi@legalpi ~ $ uname -a
Linux legalpi 4.0.7+ #802 PREEMPT Wed Jul 8 17:35:23 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You may want to use `sleep n && chromium-browser` (with `n` is the number of seconds to wait for your server to fully start up) instead of just `chromium-browser`.

Comment: Or a while loop around an appropriate pgrep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke chromium on a local HTML file that looks like this:

```
<script>
function vico_func()
{
    location = "URL_to_your_server";
}

setTimeout(vico_func, 3000);
</script>
```

`setTimeout(some_function, delay)`
is like the `at` command — it schedules the function
to be called in the future, after a delay,
which is expressed in milliseconds. 
So the above will cause chromium to go to your server page
three seconds after it is started.

You can condense this a little, using an anonymous function:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() { location = "URL_to_your_server"; }, 3000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you launch `chromium` in/by `node.js` once the server is up and running?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Until less than an hour ago, I was not able to comment.

Comment: And, *please switch on your brain*: the problem is that chromium is launched before the node.js server is serving anything. **So**, I'm proposing to launch chromium using node.js, within the JS script, right after the server is up and running. This could even be implemented as a callback since this is ususal JS.

Comment: And one last thing. Some questions are not meant to be answered, either because they are rhetorical or because they are suggestions.

Comment: Thank you @LTP, your solution works well. It could be the accepted answer as well, I tested it and it works fine.

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: @Vico: no problem. :)